# Why is index scan used instead of index seek?

Tags: sql, sql-server, clustered-index

I created unique, clustered indices on two large tables that I have to join, but those indices are not used as evidenced by the query plan. When I force the use of those indices with a hint, an index scan is used and performance gets much worse. The unique key of one table is the foreign key of the second table, so this puzzles me. Here is the schema. The two tables are `LOC` and `POL`. `LOC` has 7 million odd rows, and `POL` has over 6 million rows.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[LOC](
    [acct_num] [char](30) NOT NULL,
    [cntr_num] [char](30) NOT NULL,
    [lob_cde] [char](2) NOT NULL,
    [ste_locn_nme] [char](30) NOT NULL,
    [buldg_num] [char](20) NOT NULL,
    [prctr_cde] [char](3) NULL,
        ...more fields...
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_All] ON [dbo].[LOC] 
(
    [acct_num] ASC,
    [cntr_num] ASC,
    [lob_cde] ASC,
    [buldg_num] ASC,
    [prctr_cde] ASC,
    [spcl_cond_1_id] ASC,
    [spcl_cond_2_id] ASC,
    [spcl_cond_3_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_LOC_PKEY] ON [dbo].[LOC] 
(
    [acct_num] ASC,
    [lob_cde] ASC,
    [prctr_cde] ASC,
    [cntr_num] ASC,
    [ste_locn_nme] ASC,
    [buldg_num] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]

... more non-unique indices on LOC, each on single columns: buldg_num, prctr_cde, acct_num

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[POL](
    [acct_num] [char](30) NOT NULL,
    [cntr_num] [char](30) NOT NULL,
    [lob_cde] [char](2) NOT NULL,
    [prctr_cde] [char](3) NULL,
        ...more fields...
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_All] ON [dbo].[POL] 
(
    [acct_num] ASC,
    [cntr_num] ASC,
    [lob_cde] ASC,
    [prctr_cde] ASC,
    [acct_nme] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_POL_PKEY] ON [dbo].[POL] 
(
    [acct_num] ASC,
    [lob_cde] ASC,
    [prctr_cde] ASC,
    [cntr_num] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]

... more non-unique indices on POL, each on single columns: cntr_num, prctr_cde
```

As you can see, the four fields of the POL table's unique key (`acct_num, lob_cde, prctr_cde, cntr_num`) are the first four columns of the `LOC` table's primary key. Here is one query I want to run, like many that will join these two tables:

```
select 
      [Easy matches] = COUNT(*)
FROM LOC INNER JOIN POL ON (
        LOC.acct_num = POL.acct_num 
    AND LOC.lob_cde = POL.lob_cde 
    AND LOC.prctr_cde = POL.prctr_cde
    AND LOC.cntr_num = POL.cntr_num)
```

Without hints, this likes to use the `IDX_prctr_cde` index from each table. The `prctr_cde` column is not very selective; there are only seven different values in the `LOC` or `POL` tables. If I hint that the query should use `IDX_cntr_num` index, I get good performance, since it is a highly selective column (over 6 million distinct values in each table). `acct_num` is almost as selective as `cntr_num`, also with over 6 million distinct values.

Why is a non-selective index used by default? Why is switching to using the unique, clustered index making the query run much slower? (10x, 20x or even 30x slower.)

Note: The hint I used was:

```
OPTION ( 
        TABLE HINT(POL, INDEX (IDX_POL_PKEY)),
        TABLE HINT(LOC, INDEX (IDX_LOC_PKEY))
       )
```

Note: I am using SQL Server 2005 and SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Well, since you want the `COUNT(*)`, SQL Server must scan all rows - one way or another. In order to minimize the amount of data that needs to be read, just to determine the count, the query optimizer will try and use the **smallest** possible index - the one with the fewest bytes per index entry which results in the fewest bytes to be read from disk to scan the whole set of data.

Comment: That makes sense for the index scan on one of the tables. By when it is scanning that index, why is it not using an index seek to the other table to find the matching row? I have tried hinting only one table in the join, but still I get a scan on both tables.

Comment: Your clustered index is ***HUGE***! 115 byte - for a single entry! This is really horribly bad. The clustering key is replicated into every nonclustered index - that's the most duplicated data structure inside SQL Server. It should ideally be a **4 byte `INT`** or something like that - 115 bytes is **massive** - no wonder your queries (esp. on the clustered index) take long ... with this, **every** non-clustered index you have will **also** include all 6 columns that make up the clustering key - all 115 bytes of it!

Comment: So even your index on `lob_cde` which is `char(2)` and thus 2 bytes, will not be 7 million times 2 bytes = 14 million bytes - it's really 7 million times **115 bytes** = 805 million bytes. What a waste!

Comment: That explains things. I didn't know that bit about the clustered index key being added to every other index. Ouch! I think I will turn my clustered indexc into a non-clustered one, or just ditch it.